# How to pass minus sign (-) over url in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass minus sign (-) over url in javascript.I would like to be able to pass the url like this one,

http://test.com/events/Junin-Salsa-Congress-2013/

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        function js_tuh(){
        <?php
            foreach ($words as $word){
        ?>
            var id_tuh=document.getElementById("<?php echo str_replace(' ', '-', $word->name); ?>");
             if(id_tuh.checked==true){

            window.location = "<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>/events  /"+id_tuh.value; 
             }
            <?php }?>
            }
        </script>
```

But unfortunately the code redirects my selected site without minus sign(-). Like this one

http://test.com/events/Junin Salsa Congress 2013/

Comment: Is your javascript executed at all? I'm missing too much context to answer this question propertly.

Comment: Have you trued `id_tuh.id` instead of `id_tuh.value`?

Comment: Are you sure that id_tuh.value has propper value with '-' ?

Comment: thanks Kolink. I have just added id_tuh.id on my code and it works. Also thanks to others for trying to help me.